# How can I view the design specs in adobe xd (Developing android and ios app)

Tags: adobe-xd

How can I read the design specs in adobe xd (Developing android and ios app)

I am developing an app. But the adobe xd can able to download and can able to view the downloaded images. I can't able to see the design specifications.

How can I see the design specifications by clicking each button(how the margin spacings, spacing beween two elements etc..)